# Remove old automatically inserted "Possible duplicate" from questions

Tags: discussion

Earlier "Possible duplicate" was a real edit by Community ♦ - I suggest to remove

```
> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> [text](link)  

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

from old questions and place modern duplicate notifications.

Comment: Your suggestion would be more useful if you explained how it would benefit the community. Why should they? What problem are you solving? If it's not causing any harm then there's no real reason to make a retroactive change like that.

Comment: The Stack Exchange team no doubt has much more important issues to take care of.

Comment: I agree with @Cupcake.  Think of the reams of [joke comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261076/are-inoffensive-tongue-in-cheek-comments-considered-bad-form) that need a-purging.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly I like coming accross those. Exploring stack overflow for additional answers, can open up new ways of thinking about a problem. Why would they want to delete these?

Comment: He's not proposing deleting them. He's proposing replacing the old banners with the new ones.