# Are inoffensive tongue-in-cheek comments considered bad form?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

SO can be a fairly humorless place sometimes, and on occasion I see a post that is begging for an inoffensive remark that would hopefully give the poster a bit of a laugh.  Now humor is always subjective of course, but would it be bad form to give a light hearted comment (not answer) on a question?

Here's an example.  This user is asking for help [finding the position of his car in a game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318753/getting-an-scnphysicsvehicles-position).  The question isn't stellar, but it just made me want to say something about a satnav always helps me find the position of my car (I know, it's a bad joke, but it illustrates the point).

But it raises the question: Is it bad form to give light-hearted comments on to posts because it doesn't actually help to solve the problem?  If so, I shall continue to refrain from inflicting my very poor sense of humor on anyone :)

Comment: But .. satnav is _useless_ when he realizes that he forgot to first find the keys.

Comment: @TimPost My handbag has a portable black hole in it.  It's not a matter of forgetting to find my keys as much as having to navigate warped time and space! :)

Comment: I am so thankful to the person that came up with the term 'messenger bag' so men could have purses. Now I have a portable black hole too!

Comment: LOL @TimPost, I know a few guys who couldn't live without their man bags :)

Comment: @intracept Hacker News or Reddit would be a better fit to speak freely and make whatever joke you want :) This is a professional site that has other goals.

Comment: @abdellahmansur And I am a professional software developer ;)  It has simply been my experience that offering a human touch can help someone learn or at least feel more comfortable and be more receptive to learning.  But you are quite right that a comment that offers no value to the poster has no place here. :)

Comment: And I don't doubt it :P As you can see, a smiley here and there already accomplishes offering a human touch in a psychological way while still retaining a professional attitude :)

Comment: @abdellahmansur Hacker News has its own standards too though. Sure, a witty one-liner *might* receive a bunch of upvotes, but in general, thought-provoking discussion is encouraged and valued, not stupid jokes.

Comment: @Cupcake Who said my jokes were stupid!  Oh wait.. :)

Comment: I've seen several joke comments on various sub-sites at SE. I guess it's simply a matter of context. If there is a good number of formal/helpful answers already (or if the user getting them won't be a problem) I don't think a one-off joke will do any harm! Plus a joke+genuine answer or comment would always be welcome I suppose, even if the actual SE policy may not be so permissive.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is a place for tongue-in-cheek humor on Stack Overflow, but it takes *quite* a bit of finesse to pull it off. The comment has to be something informative, something of *value* that could conceivably influence an edit to improve the post, just delivered in a comical way.

Most attempts at this that folks make will fail; either the comment will be interpreted as being noise and removed, or you *do* manage to inspire an edit and it becomes obsolete, which is also a reason for comments to vanish. But, those gems that remain - they add a *tiny* human touch to something otherwise quite sterile and many people do appreciate them.

On meta, as you've seen - feel free to unwind a bit. As Cupcake [points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261077/50049) we *do* occasionally clean up comment threads that degenerated into absurdity, but it generally has to be a *really* high value of absurdity before we'd do that. Here, we're much more likely to vaporize mud-slinging over comical banter, and even make our own feeble attempts at comic relief where it's warranted.

Comment: "But, those gems that remain - they add a *tiny* human touch to something otherwise quite sterile and many people do appreciate them." What's that? Tiny *human touch*? ***GET THIS FILTH OFF OF MY Q&A!***

Comment: I think this was kind of the point behind my question.  I often use humor in my job as a way of breaking the ice which can make people more receptive to the message you are trying to give them.  When you can both entertain and inform, it's a rare gift.  I wish I had it.  Hmm, either of then, actually :)

Comment: @pnuts do you have a Jeff quote for "SE should be fun"? There's [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), but I'm not sure if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Used to be in the FAQ, @Cupcake. It's now in the help center, but you'll have to dig a bit.

Comment: In regards to this, why is JAtwood's comment okay on this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/456823/2106228

That is in no way productive to the discussion at hand, but it has 4 upvotes. Is it only acceptable because He's Jeff Atwood or is there a better reason for that to exist? (Honestly trying to learn here, not argue)

Answer (score 4):

The trouble with joke comments is that they might be funny at the moment, for a moment, but they don't usually add *lasting* value. Adding a joke or lighthearted comment can serve an important purpose -- it can make someone feel like they're among friends, provide encouragement, or counteract an unnecessarily negative comment or answer. But these are usually temporary situations, and a joke is often less funny and less relevant once that situation passes, especially after edits.

If you're going to add a less than serious comment to a post, keep an eye on it and **delete it when it's no longer helpful or relevant.**