# Teaching People to Read Documentation

Tags: discussion

For many questions posted to Stack Overflow, the questioner could have solved the problem themselves in a few minutes of reading the documentation. However, much as the workings of a `for` loop seem so much more obvious to an experienced programmer, it occurs to me that the instinct to go for the manual and the knowledge of how to efficiently read it are not obvious and innate to all people.

How can we help people learn to RTFM? Beyond simply telling people to do it, what resources can we provide to teach them to do it? What kind of comments should we leave? Is it just something that needs practice before it becomes second nature, or are there specific documentation-locating and documentation-reading techniques we should point out? Is there a canonical question to link to (and if so, is it structured in a way that's useful to the people it targets)?

Comment: How about just answering the question? Maybe include in your answer an explanation of how you found the information—where you looked, what the relevant sections of the manual were, etc.

Comment: To learn how to answer questions, I suggest reading the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm not seeing how that relates to the topic. If you're talking about how to answer other people's questions, that's not what this is about. If you're talking about how to answer your own questions, the help center doesn't seem to go into much more detail than "search first".

Comment: @user2357112: I was making a joke based off of Cody's comment about answering questions and the topic of RTFM in general. To be fair, it was a really bad joke.

Comment: @user, sometimes we have to face the facts and realize some of these users cannot be helped. For instance, we have an <expletive> *interstitial* to guide new users when they post questions, yet we routinely deal with utter crap. Some people just *don't read*, be it the fine manual or anything else.

Comment: @CodyGray: Explaining how you found the information is probably helpful. I feel like it might not be enough, though. I'm not particularly knowledgeable about education or education research, so I don't know how effective showing someone how you solved a problem is at teaching them to solve it, but my gut feeling is that there might be more widely effective approaches.

Comment: Really, though. I wouldn't be surprised if Stack Overflow *assumed* a user had manual-reading skills already. This is why downvotes are used to indicate lack of research effort. There is no need to invest resources in teaching someone something they're expected to know by the time they come here.

Comment: Well yeah, I mean, I didn't say it would work. People who are unwilling to help themselves are generally unwilling to help themselves. You aren't going to teach someone how to help themselves if they are uninterested in learning it. I don't think you'll find any approaches that circumvent that basic problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Did you read the last EULA you agreed to? Or the last interstitial ad you had to sit through? Did you read the manual for the last video game or electronic doohickey you bought? For me, the answers are all "no", so I can't really blame other people for not reading.

Comment: @user, honestly, in order: yes, no (I run a proxy that shields me from most ads / interstitials) and yes. (I have to admit I'm probably the last guy around that reads the manual before booting a game, but so there).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Impressive. It's been a while since the last time I read a EULA, and I'm not sure whether I got all the way through.

Comment: @BoltClock: Well, if we're expecting people to know how to read the manual, our assumptions may need to be corrected. I don't know in which life experiences people are expected to pick up the skill, but even among programmers and prospective programmers, I don't think they're universal. I'm not sure where I picked it up myself; I can't remember any course, book, or site that taught it.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, that was probably [my fault](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261076/are-inoffensive-tongue-in-cheek-comments-considered-bad-form).  Sorry :)

Comment: Here is one approach I quite liked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403628/how-can-i-search-for-delphi-documentation

Comment: And what if the manual is incomprehensible ? I regularly try to find answers in the C++ Standard and believe me, not only is it difficult finding what you are looking for, but even when you found a related nugget there might be overarching rules (that you missed) or exceptions (elsewhere) that you need to take into account to obtain the final answer. Oh, and sometimes even with all the pieces the actual intent requires more divination than logic. *How high do you place the bar ?*

Comment: The stated purpose of SO is to create a library of Questions and Answers. It doesn't say anything about *not creating redundancy with the documentation*, but outlines specific opinions about *"offline resources"*. I would say that teaching people to fish is generally a good thing, but outside the scope of this site. If you can answer the question, answer it. If the questions is a duplicate or inappropriate close it. End of story.

Comment: You know, many folks do try to learn from Documentation (at least on game dev exchange), but sometimes, the documentation does not really help, or is in a language that a foreigner would not get it right. I would recommend asking in a comment if the person checked the docs, then proceed with the answer you receive. If they did not, well, I would give a -1 and tell the person to look into it before posting a question. We have to incentivate the person to research more, right?

Comment: @nsfyn55 It does actually.  The site has made it clear that it expects questions to have been researched, so that questions that are already readily discoverable do not waste the time of the community.

Comment: Good point to think about, 
The problem is that the documentation sometimes just complicates things simple, 
And sometimes hard to find what you want, so it easy sometimes to understand why people ask simple questions 
And just to answer or give a link directory and so they'll know where to look next time

Comment: @Servy *"expects questions to have been researched"* ... agreed. But I believe this is saying *"Have you narrowed your problem down to the point where a concise answer can be given?"* not *"Is this something you could have looked up?"*. One of the top voted answers on this site is *"How do I revert a commit in git"* should the top answer be `man git-revert`?

Comment: @nsfyn55 Both are very important aspects of that requirement, not just one or the other.

Comment: @Servy so you believe that that `revert` post should be closed because its clearly outlined in the reference material? Even though it has 1000's of upvotes? And has helped countless people?

Comment: In addition I would go as far as to say there I believe there are only three sets (S1(questions that are topically appropriate), S2(questions that are on SO), S3(questions that aren't on SO)). If its in the intersection of S1 and S3 it should be left open.

Comment: @nsfyn55 The post is adding **zero value** to the programming community.  Every single person that was helped by that information would have found the exact same information with the exact same amount of effort had the question never existed in the first place, because they'd simply have found the documentation, seen the *exact same content*, and that would be that.  Stealing content from an official source only to stuff it with your own ads while you work to get it better Google Juice isn't actually adding value to the world.

Comment: @Servy I think that is where we diverge. The stated goal of the site is as follows *"With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to **every** question about programming."*. You must note it does not say *"every question that can't easily be searched somewhere else"*

Comment: also to Jean-Francois's point what you end up with is documentation here on SO that is accurate, accessible, and well-organized. Milling through crap documentation and spitting out a sensible knowledge base is what this site does best.

Comment: @nsfyn55 no, the goal is not to cover every single programming question.  There are all sorts of categories of programming questions that are out of scope for the site.  The goal of the site is to improve the scope of programming knowledge accessible to the world by providing quality questions and quality answers.  Taking other people's content and sticking our ads on it doesn't help accomplish that.  Actually *generating original content* does.

Comment: @Servy *"the goal is not to cover every single programming question"*  You say that yet the site's **mission statement** found here(http://stackoverflow.com/tour) **directly** contradicts you. **every** is a powerful word yet they still use it. I believe this means its incumbent on you either to campaign to modify this mission or petition webster's to redefine **every** to the Servy definition which appears to be *"kinda, sorta everything, but really what I mean is up to my subjective approval of what is original and adds value"*.

Comment: @nsfyn55 The site doesn't intend to have answers to subjective questions, or unclear questions, or broad questions, or highly localized questions, etc.  There are *plenty* of instances in which the site has focused its scope in order to improve the quality of content it provides.  If you read paste that sentence, the page that you yourself just linked to goes on to explain all sorts of *programming questions that aren't welcome here*.  This includes (wait for it), "Don't ask about...Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: @Servy agreed. But notice in your list of inappropriate questions you didn't include *"could easily be found in the documentation"*.

Comment: @nsfyn55 Actually, it does...explicitly, on the page that you linked to.

Comment: @Servy I can only assume you are referring to this *"Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"* which is not the same as *"Exists in the documentation"*. Everything is in the documentation. But most documentation sucks

Comment: @nsfyn55 It is a subset of that case.  If the documentation answers your question, then you shouldn't be asking about that question; if you do ask it, then you didn't try to find an answer.  If the documentation *doesn't* answer that question, then obviously we're not in the situation described here.  There is *plenty* of *very good* documentation out there.  Yes, there is also bad documentation.  If the documentation doesn't answer your question, then it's appropriate to ask about on SO.  When it does, it isn't.

Comment: @nsfyn55 Keep in mind that you yourself were talking about cases of copy-pasting the information from the documentation to the SO question as examples of good question.  If the documentation is good enough to just copy-paste into an answer then your argument that the documentation will be of lower quality clearly doesn't hold.

Comment: @Servy I think paraphrasing documentation is more than appropriate. Part of what makes documentation suck is not just the content but the organization. I am checking out on this abuse of comments, but my final word SO is about building **this** library. It can/should have overlap with the documentation. I can/will/should answer questions that could be answered with copious offline research. I want to be able to find an answer to **every** one of my questions without leaving this site. If you think that is wrong then so be it.

Comment: @nsfyn55 It's not a question of whether I think it's wrong.  The official SO guidelines *say* that it's wrong.  Your assertion that it states otherwise is false, because it *very clearly says the opposite of your claim*.  You're saying that you know what you're doing is wrong, *and you just don't care*.

Comment: @Servy - You love to reference the *"guidelines"* but you loathe to quote directly. I just thoroughly read these two links `how-to-answer` and `how-to-ask`. It makes *exactly* zero reference to whether an answer exists somewhere else. It simply says "research your question". A *GREAT* question/answer can have almost 100% overlap with the documentation and usually does. A *GREAT* question is about organization. "Is it well worded?", "Is it narrow in its scope?", "is it clear in its purpose?", "will it be useful to someone else?". There is nothing exclusive between these and existing elsewhere.

Comment: @nsfyn55 Except I [did quote them directly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261091/teaching-people-to-read-documentation?noredirect=1#comment45805_261091)...As to your last comment, "research your question" is absolutely a reference to whether an answer exists somewhere else.  So your claim that "it makes zero reference" to something followed by a quote of it referencing *exactly that* is rather...humorous.

Comment: Maybe we could start earlier and teach people to read...

Comment: @Servy I am not convinced you actually read anything I put in here as your threshold for tl;dr seems to be about .5 sentences. This site is not here for your benefit. It is a library. The tags **ARE** documentation and often better documentation than the official documentation. All I am saying is that the maintainers of those tags should not be concerning themselves with duplicates of things in the official documentation, but should only be considering whether a duplicate exists on SO.

Comment: @nsfyn55 And that sentiment is strictly in violation of the site's policy.  You may *want* that to be the case, but that is in violation of what SO's guidelines state.  *You* think that SO is official documentation, but it is not.  You think that SO should plagiarize all of the internet's existing programming content, but again site policy says otherwise.

Comment: @Servy I don't think its official documentation, but its documentation nonetheless, and often better than the official documentation. It absolutely is **not** a violation of any policy that I am aware of to cite the official documentation. Do you care to provide a direct quote?

Comment: @nsfyn55 It's in violation of policies that *you yourself quoted to me*.  Your assertion that documentation is of universally low quality is also simply wrong, and also an irrelevant point.  Once again, if the documentation *doesn't* answer the question, then sure, by all means, answer it.  When it does answer it adequately, it shouldn't be duplicated here.  The fact that you're bringing up cases where the SO answer is doing nothing but *copying the documentation* it is pretty obvious that the documentation *isn't* inadequate, given that it's just being quoted after all.

Comment: @Servy hey there welcome to straw man junction don't forget to wipe your feet. I never said all documentation was low quality. I never said to copy documentation directly without citation. I said having answers **REDUNDANT** with documentation was more than acceptable and I gave you a great example regarding `git revert`. I am saying having an answer that addresses a common problem that is also **COVERED** in the documentation is not a problem and is actually one of the goals of this site. And that tag maintainers should only be concerned with whether a question is **COVERED** on SO

Comment: @nsfyn55 And I explained to you why an SO answer that does nothing but quote documentation, such as the extremely low quality answer you provided, is in violation of the site's policy.  SO users should *absolutely* be concerned with what information is readily accessible outside of the world of SO, because questions are expected to represent research effort, and not so much as looking at the documentation for the specific thing you are asking a question about is about is a very obvious indication of a lack of research effort.

Comment: @Servy the reason this is such a frustrating and unproductive conversation is that every time I say something you build a fanciful straw man then talk about that. Then my reply has to be 1) deconstruct your straw man 2) try to salvage some piece of what you said to make a valid point. If you want to continue do me a favor. A) Stick to the facts B) address what I am actually saying. I keep saying this is a library of all valid on-topic questions. Not just those that are not covered in the documentation. If you want to cite a policy that expressedly forbids overlap with the docs then fine do so.

Comment: I never once mentioned any question I gave an answer to low-quality or otherwise. I cited this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-the-last-git-commit). I never said documentation was universally low quality although you brought that up several times, I never advocated plagiarism though you accused me of it. Its very difficult for me not to take offense to your approach and see it as anything but obstructionist.

Comment: @nsfyn55 I have.  [I even linked you to it when you claimed, falsely, that I haven't quoted it to you.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261091/teaching-people-to-read-documentation?noredirect=1#comment45827_261091)  You're continuing to ignore it.  You're making assertions of what you want to do with no basis whatsoever in site policy, despite the fact that that site policy specifically states the opposite of your claim.  The fact that you want everyone to waste their time duplicating content doesn't make it appropriate site policy.

Comment: @nsfyn55 My reference to "the answer you provided" was "the answer you provided a link to" not "the answer you posted".  You *have* claimed that ["most documentation sucks"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261091/teaching-people-to-read-documentation?noredirect=1#comment45809_261091)  That's a *very* wide sweeping generalization to make.  You have also claimed that users should be copying the exact content of the documentation in answers (which is of course conflicting with your earlier claim that it's mostly bad).

Comment: @Servy direct reference bro not this interpretive dance you think is reason. it makes zero direct reference. Thats why your entire position is specious. Because it relies on your broad interpretation of what that means. It literally makes no reference to not asking something that is in the official documentation. As a matter of fact it actually encourages you to ask if you've read the docs and don't understand them. It simply tells you to cite why.

Comment: @Servy *" You have claimed that "most documentation sucks""* I did and its true, but its far from a claim of universality. It could mean there is one more crappy doc site than there are good ones. Your hyperbolizing is going to give me an aneurism.

Comment: @nsfyn55 So you think a question that is answered by literally just quoting the documentation for the exact topic the question is asking is a well researched question?  You don't consider not even looking at the documentation for the topic you're asking about to represent a lack of research?

Comment: @Servy no I think that is a terrible answer, but here is a good answer to a good question that is also available in the documentation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982917/flask-wtforms-difference-between-datarequired-and-inputrequired/23984389#23984389). Its good even though its clearly outlined in the WTForms docs because the docs do not provide as much depth as I do. All I am/have been saying is that just because its in the docs doesn't mean it doesn't belong here too.

Comment: @nsfyn55 If most documentation sucks then why are you advocating copying all of it to SO so adamantly?  If it's really so bad then there shouldn't be any reason to copy it here to SO.  If a particular aspect of documentation is good, then *that is exactly the content that we don't need to duplicate here*.  The only content that would need to be on SO is content *that is not covered adequately in documentation*, which means that *the post shouldn't be primarily quoting documentation*.

Comment: @Servy I'll agree if you can provide a definition for **adequate**. That is universal for every person and case for all time.

Comment: @nsfyn55 It is of course inherently subjective; it becomes a judgement call that the subject experts for that field need to determine on their own.  But if an answer is merely duplicating the content *and adding no value* then they are implicitly stating that the feel the external content is already adequate.  They would need to be adding value in some form, through original content, in order to make the claim that the other content was inadequate.

Comment: @Servy No one(certainly not me) is advocating a wholesale dump of another sites documentation. I believe there is room for a lot of overlap and redundancy with documentation highlighted with explanation. I *do not* believe it is wrong for a user that has shown some due diligence to post a novel(non-duplicate) question that exists in the documentation, but not on stack overflow.

Comment: @nsfyn55 If the user has researched the topic, found the documentation *and failed to answer a given question about that topic given that information* then sure, it may well be an appropriate question worth answering.  But we absolutely don't want people coming here to ask a question because they couldn't' be bothered to even look at the documentation to see if it answers their question, nor should we be answering such questions.  It benefits *nobody*, and is harmful to *everyone*.  That is exactly what this question is about, people not even *checking* the documentation before asking.

Comment: @nsfyn55 You seem to be under the false impression that this question (or myself) is claiming that any information anywhere in any documentation cannot ever be in an SO answer, which is simply not true.  Rather SO should be a place that picks up where documentation (and other resources) leave off, not the only place anyone ever goes to find an answer to every single question.

Comment: @Servy if you did a little more asking what my *"impressions"* are instead of telling me you wouldn't be so confused. Read here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261091/teaching-people-to-read-documentation?noredirect=1#comment45703_261091. **YOU** are the progenitor of this litany. I said that SO doesn't make any policy statements about redundancy with the documentation(a position I still maintain that you just now agreed with) and that sent you off into crazyville, USA. Time after time you tell **me** what it is that **I** think. I know what I think you are the one that is confused.

Comment: @nsfyn55 So you do feel that research is important?  You feel that people asking questions should be making a good faith effort to search through existing resources, especially documentation, to look for an answer to their question before posting it, and that when a question clearly demonstrates a lack of this basic research and *is* answered by easily discoverable high quality documentation it should not be duplicated in an answer here on SO?  If you believe all of that then I was indeed confused by your earlier comments and I apologize.

Comment: @Servy - *Research == Important* I hope this puts that to bed. But I will qualify by saying I am inclined to answer a question that I know to exist in the documentation. If the question meets SO's Ask guidelines and isn't an SO duplicate. By that I mean I may not give copious critical consideration as to whether I believe the person adequately researched it.

Comment: @nsfyn55 But someone asking a question that is easily discoverable, in the documentation, and has a high quality answer there already *doesn't* meet SO's asking guidelines, which require that a good faith research effort be made before asking the question.  If you're going to claim that research is important then you need to *back up your own claim* by actually holding question askers to that, and not answering questions that demonstrate an entirely lack of research.

Comment: @Servy I would say that not all ask guidelines are created equal and my assessment is subjective to all the criteria as a whole. I will not answer a question that is vague, off-topic, or lacks a reproducible example. But if the question is crisp and concise and would be useful to a future user I will answer it. And yes this may include some questions that exist in the docs and some that a user stumbled into a good question without research. This is one of the reasons the RTFM close reason has been shot down umpteen million times.

Comment: @nsfyn55 So what you're saying is that you don't feel research is important at all, and that the fact that a question demonstrates no research whatsoever won't stop you from answering it?  When a question's answer is already readily accessible then *answering it yet again doesn't actually help people*.  *Yet another* answer to questions that get answered thousands of times a day, and to which quality answers are very easy for inexperienced users to get access to, doesn't help future users as you claim, because if your answer weren't there, they'd just see another equally good answer.

Comment: @Servy Research is still important. In fact, my comment implies that only one person can every stumble into a good novel question and that every subsequent user with that question would be held to at least researching this site or get closed as a dupe. I believe it is incumbent on answerers to keep an eye out for duplicates and focus their attention on improving the existing answer if its inadequate. Do you see a problem with this approach to building a library of answers?

Comment: @nsfyn55 So you're saying research *on SO* is important, but nobody should ever look anywhere other than SO for an answer.  And yes, I *do* have a problem with that.  Whenever people ask or answer questions to which the answers are already readily accessible (whether on SO or not) *nobody* benefits.  Everyone involved in asking or answer answering the question loses out in wasted effort, and no future visitors are ever coming across content that they wouldn't already have come across.  Whether the duplicate is on SO or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @Servy really no one benefits? Thats a rather broad assertion. It also implies that if I ask a question that has **AN** answer in the documentation that that answer is *equivalent* to the SO answer. Do you feel someone could provide an answer on SO that is superior to the docs? Do you feel *someone* benefits if the answer on SO is superior to the one found in the documentation? If you buy into those two how would you propose someone get to that superior answer without asking a question?

Comment: @nsfyn55 If someone has information that is not in the documentation that they feel is important then they should be asking/looking for a question that requires that information to be answered.  A question along the lines of, "I read the documentation, and it mostly explained [simple concept] but it didn't cover [some unusual case or modification of the problem] [...]"

Comment: Relevant xkcds: http://xkcd.com/1343/, http://xkcd.com/293/. Honestly, I have no sympathy for this attitude. Enough documentation is so bloated and incomprehensible, it's not worth scouring. To quote Thomas Sowell (although he was speaking of a different group), the authors "seemed to feel that, once they put their priceless contributions to mankind on paper, a sacred obligation fell upon the reader to do his d****est to try to figure out what they could possibly mean." If the documentation isn't clear enough for the user to understand, it's probably just not clear enough.

Comment: @Servy "The site has made it clear that it expects questions to have been researched, so that questions that are already readily discoverable do not waste the time of the community." Personally, I don't think it's a waste of time to help Google make it easier for everyone to solve their problem. Think about it. If it would take an average person 20 minutes to get through the docs and find the answer, but Googling now only takes 2 minutes to find it because it's on StackOverflow, how much time have we saved the world?

Comment: "How can we help people learn to RTFM?" - most of whom you want to tell RTFM aren't willing to do so. the rest usually doesn't need help. so the whole point is irrelevant.

Comment: Sometimes, reading documentation or copy-paste it in answers doesn't help newbies. They need it to be explained in the *context* of their code to help them understand it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4005614/1090562 questions like these are amazing.

Comment: @jpmc26 When SO contains the exact same information as the docs it's *not* any easier to access on SO.  It would be just as easy to access directly from the documentation, so now you need to adjust your math to compare 2 minutes to find the documentation and get your answer vs 2 minutes to find SO and get your answer.  Now you've spent a bunch of time and effort creating a page of content that is adding *zero value*.

Comment: @Servy Access, perhaps, but there is a *huge* difference between *accessing* and *processing*. "Documentation" is notoriously hard to process, and StackOverflow answers are, at least in a relative/comparison sense, notoriously easy. So, yes, my Google search might turn up the documentation as the first result, but I'm going to spend a bunch of time sifting through all the stuff that isn't relevant to my problem or that I already knew to begin with. And that doesn't even touch on all the good points here about subtleties not obvious from the docs.

Comment: @jpmc26 So it takes you 20 minutes to learn how to use the documentation once, and then every time thereafter it's just as fast, as you've learned how to use the site.  If people want to become successful programmers that's a skill they simply are going to need to develop.  SO simply is not going to replace the entirety of knowledge in all documentation for every language, ever.  Even if we wanted it to, it won't, and trying to do that would be *very* harmful to the site.

Comment: @Servy I dispute all your premises: 1) That you could "learn to use the documentation once" in 20 minutes. Fully learning how to use a non-trivial piece of documentation takes years of returning to again and again to know where the information you need is, and more for poor documentation. 2) That your future searches will benefit so greatly from past attempts to delve into the documentation. Often it's a matter of just hunting for what you want. 3) That questions answerable via a manual are somehow harmful to the site. Some of the most viewed questions are near trivial and don't harm anything.

Comment: @jpmc26 It doesn't take years to learn how to look through documentation.  By a few days, maybe a week or two of active development is more than enough.  The fact that *a very tiny percent* of these types of questions have garnered a lot of views doesn't mean that these questions aren't harmful.  The harm is in the effort wasted creating them, given that they add no value, and also in that they drive away experts, instead attracting less knowledgeable users to answer questions by encouraging mostly questions that simply involve googling the topic for the OP.

Answer (score 78):

[image]

I dispute the premise of this question.

We can help askers read documentation, but in order to do so we will, by definition, *write* answers and comments — a kind of documentation. In fact this documentation persists on SO and has a name: "duplicates".

Will we then have to help people RTFA and RTFC? By writing more answers and comments? (Related: http://xkcd.com/1343/)

This leads to an intractable "[turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)" meta-problem.

My answer is: **Just point to the documentation*.** Let the user have a shot at it. **If** the user tries to apply it and fails, then they can ask a question about that including what they tried, which is fine. If.

<sub>* In a comment, of course. Link-only answers suck. So do answers to non-RTFM questions more generally.</sub>

Comment: Your premise seems to be that the person read the documentation and was confused by it, not that they couldn't bother to read it so they wanted someone else to copy-paste it in an answer to them.

Comment: So instead, we should grab the entire documentation for that language, and put it in an incredibly large pastebin, and link to that pastebin in our answer, or just put the whole section of that documentation in the answer.

Comment: The problem is that so much documentation is complete garbage. "Self-documenting code", for example is great for people who are experienced in both the programming language and the concepts being documented but not so great for people who are trying to learn either. I have seen *so* many libraries have great use of the language documented but have completely unhelpful documentation of exactly *what* it's supposed to do.

Comment: @inetknght I guess people who want to read the manual but do not understand it may need a general programming course or a tutorial. Obviously there is bad documentation out there but also a lot of good one and most simple questions on SO could really be solved by reading more before.

Comment: @Trilarion: excepting the fact that a lot of boost libraries' documentation interfaces are complete crap, a lot of their actual documentation content is quite unhelpful too. There's libraries whose sole documentation is a doxygen pass on the headers.

Comment: As someone that tries to write documentation for my own stuff, I find that I tend to have to spend at least twice or thrice as much time explaining how to use it or how it works compared to the amount of time required to understand the problem and provide a solution. It is reasonable that there's a lot of terrible documentation, if it even exists...

Comment: @inetknght If, for a particular topic, the documentation doesn't cover it, or doesn't cover it effectively, and there are no other readily available solutions to the problem, then sure, SO is a great place to ask about it and get a good answer.  But to assume that all documentation is universally bad and never worth using is just wrong.  When the documentation covers a particular topic adequately, there is no need for that question to be asked on SO.

Comment: @inetknght Just went to the boost page and found more than just headers [Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm). But I don't want to fight over the quality of any documentation. Of course you can always make it better. And maybe this is the reason why SO exists.

Comment: I'm not going to argue semantics. Boost has gotten better in recent releases about having more than *just* headers as documentation. However, there's also the question about actually getting answers from people. Thankfully, you're right, SO is usually fairly good about that. :)

Comment: Loads of Swing documentation is of the form "Frobs the foo according to bar", with no link to foo or indication of what it's for, no link to bar or indication of how to make one, and no indication of what frobbing might involve.

Comment: @Servy: How is that my premise? Or did you mean the OP's premise?

Comment: Admitting I upvoted this for humor...

Comment: Just point the user at the documentation = link only answer.

Comment: @podiluska: ... link-only comment?

Comment: iOS documentation is abysmal.. this issue is platform-specific.

Answer (score 29):

One of the best features of S/O, in my opinion, is the fact that so often it succeeds where documentation fails.  This is for one of two reasons: the documentation is insufficient, or does not contain a good searching mechanism.  Stack overflow (often via Google) is superbly searchable, and so it is often *much* faster to find the answer to a question here than it is to RTFM.

If someone asks a good quality (short, sweet, useful, non-duplicate) question, I think that's great even if the answer is in the manual.  If nobody feels like bothering to answer it, that's fine too.

On a related note, my favorite answers often have a bonus link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: **If** the documentation fails to effectively answer the question then yes, SO is absolutely a great resource, but when users go and ask and SO question without even bothering to read the documentation, as you are advocating, it is *highly* wasteful of *everyone's* time and effort.  Merely reading the documentation, when it contains a quality answer to your question, is *far* faster and easier than posting an SO question and waiting for an answer, it doesn't waste the community's time, it doesn't clog search results, etc.  The flood of low quality questions like these also drives away experts.

Comment: I agree with some of your points, but not that it is wasteful. I've profited from it greatly just using Google day-to-day to look up trivial things (commands, etc.) that I've forgotten. Is S/O really only for experts to ask other experts questions?

Comment: And if the SO question wasn't there you'd just have found the documentation it was quoting, got your same answer, and been equally well off.  SO added zero value to you in those instances.  It adds value when SO is the only resource that has an answer to your question, or when it's answers are of far greater quality.  When the answer of equal quality is already available, zero value was added.

Comment: "It adds value when SO is the only resource that has an answer to your question" SO is never the only resource that has an answer. If you are wondering why the questions that have hundreds of upvotes are often the most simple, RTFM type questions, it's because they have saved thousands of people meaningful chunks of time. Upvotes may not imply quality, but they do imply value.  Thus, not a waste of time for the community.  Just don't click on the question if it's too trivial for your taste.

Comment: But every single one of those people would have found the exact same information, in the exact same amount of effort, if that question never existed in the first place.  No value was created from those users, value was simply taken away from the documentation (or whatever else is now in second place in the Google search for that post) in equal measure to whatever SO created.  It saved thousands of people **exactly zero** chucks of time, contrary to your claim.

Comment: I disagree with you, and the bit about "value being taken away from the documentation" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Imagine a site that just goes around re-posting every single SO question/answer on its own site, but also sticking in a bunch of their own ads into the content so that they make money.  [There's a ton of these sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers).  Do you think they're adding value?  are the many thousands of people that get helpful answers there benefiting from the existence of that site?  No, if those sites didn't exist, those users would just find SO instead, and get their same quality answer with the same amount of effort.

Comment: It's not the same thing, although I see where you're going with it.  The difference, though, is SO creates new content, curates it beautifully, and puts it somewhere where it can be easily found and voted upon so the cream rises to the top.

Comment: It's *exactly* the same thing, at least in the cases under discussion, namely cases where high quality solutions to the problem at hand are already readily available.  When the content placed on SO is not already readily available in other very high quality sources, sure, it does those things.  When the official documentation already has all of that information in a quality canonical source then no, it's not adding value.

Comment: @AlexMA: I'm with you 100%. In fact, part of the original vision for Stack Overflow (and people can of course disagree with whether that vision still applies, or still *should* apply) is that it becomes the ultimate repository of programming knowledge. Implicit in that is that it will contain information that is already in other sources. But SO isn't meant to be (merely) links to those sources, it is meant to have the *actual knowledge* as content, in the form of questions and answers.

Comment: @Servy What's the alternative, that wastes less time?

Comment: @BenAaronson Don't waste your time answering questions that already have high quality readily accessible answers.  Spend your time answering questions to which quality answers are not readily available instead.

Answer (score 8):

I think learning by doing will work.
The trick is how to get people to start reading in the documentation at all.

**Suggestion:**

Mention in your answer the existence of some interesting additional information
about the topic.
Do **not** explain that information, but include a hyperlink to it.

I think this can work well in [short answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules/1032653#1032653)
as well as [longer ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript/7220510#7220510).

Answer (score 7):

Personally I like this approach:

> From [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat): "Return Value -- On success, zero is returned. On error, `-1` is returned, and `errno` is set appropriately."
>
> This is followed by a list of `errno` codes and their causes.  Which one of these is causing your failure will be apparent when you check the value of `errno`.  The `perror` and `strerror` functions can automatically map the numeric value of `errno` to a short description.

It provides the next step in debugging (check `errno`), proves that what they need is in the documentation (the man page, specifically), and doesn't save them from actually having to read the documentation themselves.

The link too is helpful, but there are other ways to get a copy of the man page, so even if the link breaks the answer is still useful.

Answer (score 3):

Answer the question *and* point them at the documentation.
My currently [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790789/781965) does this, and it seemed well-received.

This way, the first time a question about something comes up, we can respond, and every other time just point the asker the way of the answer, just like we always do on SO. It's not rude, doesn't push anyone away from the community, and still points out that you should RTFM. Typically questions like this can be answered in just a line or two, and if it can't then it's probably a question worth asking anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the search in the documentation is not obvious. Python has great docs, that are divided amongst the library reference, the tutorial and some technical essays (not counting unofficial documentation). In this case, teach the asker how you know how to get to the documentation, and how to find it.

In other occasions, there is some jargon involved. It is easy to search the documentation, if you know the name (for example, views in Numpy arrays). Here, teach the jargon.

Other cases, the answer can be found by simply typing the post in your favourite search engine in the first three results. In that case, vote to close due to insufficient research.

Answer (score -1):

@user2357112 
First, you're right that going for the manual is against the instinct and intuition of people, which is totally natural. There are no manuals in nature.

Having documentation that explains how to operate something, is a sign of imperfection, it means that the product is not self-explanatory, it has usability issues, it's arbitrary and 
unintuitive, it's interface is a puzzle that people can't solve and therefore it requires from the manufacturer or programmer to reveal the missing information -the information that the product fails to communicate to the user.

We all should aim to make products that don't need explanations. That goal alone will lead to human-compatible products, products with perfect usability.

Second, the point of your question is oxymoron. You post a question on a website about answering questions how to convince people who ask questions to leave the site and go find the answer in the manual instead!

Comment: Unsurprisingly, not that many agree with what I wrote. Obviously half of them consider that our current primitive era will be eternal, and the other half are those who make those arbitrary puzzling interfaces or write those lousy manuals and don't have a clue about how to make them better.

Answer (score -2):

Should Stack Overflow really become the type of community where we redirect people away with a fierce and sarcastic mention to "Go read the manual!"? The only approach I see that doesn't deplete the usefulness of this wonderful community is to suggest ways the user could've answered their own question **AFTER** answering their question.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely it should

Comment: @podiluska Elaborate on how that is a good way to go about a community. I find it narrow-minded to think this would - in any way - be beneficial.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow or http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late

Comment: @podiluska That is not elaborating on how it's a good way to go about a community. That's linking to discussion about the very issue I'm trying to bring forward. There is **no** reason to push people away because they don't follow the meta on S/O when they registered yesterday. We should welcome every new member, and make efforts to help them adapt to the community. Snide remarks won't do this. Read the accepted answer on [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late). It kind of describes what I'm out for.

Comment: Except other answers to that have higher votes. Users that can't be bothered to RTFM should be treated with disdain. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back/

Comment: @podiluska The votecount doesn't change what I used as an example to describe my thoughts. You're making wild and broad statement where you generalize people saying they can't be bothered to read the manual. This doesn't describe even nearly all cases being discussed, where the author is often new to the language and/or can't find the proper documentation - or even knows what to look for. Sit on a throne and look down upon these people genuinly seeking advice all you want, but in my book, that makes you a horrible member of this community, and I look on _you_ with disdain.

Comment: Yes, when users are asking questions that consume the community's resources, add zero value to the site, but have a high cost, we should *absolutely* be encouraging them to read the manual first.  SO was built with the premise that not all content is good content.  It was designed to be a repository of *quality* questions with *quality* answers that will attract experts.  Flooding the site with questions that just involve googling the question and posting the answer back to the user drives away experts.

Comment: Oh, and to whoever downvoted this when all I'm doing is trying to make a point very valid to the discussion - merry christmas.

Comment: @MarcusFrölander Voting on meta indicates disagreement - RTFM : http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta (QED :) )

Comment: @podiluska "On posts tagged **feature-request**, voting indicates agreement or disagreement". Read it yourself.

Comment: @MarcusFrölander When that traffic is encouraging more people to waste more of the community's time then that traffic that they are adding is *harming* the site, not helping it.  Yes, flooding the site *does* drive away experts.  When SO was first created it was designed with the premise of discouraging low quality questions which is *why so many experts came to SO in the first place*.

Comment: @MarcusFrölander Sure, I've never supported being rude, but not answering low quality questions, and instead expecting the user to do some basic research first, is not inherently rude.

Comment: @Servy I completely agree! :)

Answer (score -4):

I see this as two questions: *What is 'good' documentation?*

...And: *'Why do users come to Stack Overflow, even when I can show them good documentation that answers their question'?*

There's no short answer to either question, so please take a moment to read a long one. If you don't have the time, here's the very, very short answer to the first one:

**Manuals and documentation in general are written for more than one audience, and often they must be 'split out' into separate documents.**

The common failure modes are:

- Sometimes, users are reading the wrong one;
- Sometimes, users have been *given* the wrong one and have no way of knowing that the other ones exist;
- But, all too often, you have only provided one of them.

#### So what are 'The Documents' that constitute a good Manual?

I'm going to explain this using the example of a typical piece of commercial software, rather than for programming in general and the particular questions asked by developers on Stack Overflow because it allows me to lay out the principles and the categories of a good manual in a structured way.

Nevertheless, the principles of good documentation hold true for notepad.exe, or for the vast and complex world of Visual Studio for Enterprise; the differences lie in choosing *which* category of documentation needs to be prioritised, and how it should be presented.

And, of course, on recognising which developers count as beginners, 'occasional users', experts, and 'Support Manual' users in terms of how they need to use the documentation. This is not as easy as you think, and it is often done badly: you should ask yourself *"Who was the intended audience for this documentation"* before concluding that the reason it is useless, to you, is that the authors are useless.

You will still be correct in drawing this conclusion, more often than not: good technical authors are rare, and the role is not valued in most software houses.

So here's the basic documentation set for a moderately complex piece of software:

#### Getting Started:

1. Congratulations on purchasing ACME software's latest product!
2. Here's how to get it up and running;
3. These are the three most common task you will perform, with a brief explanation and short set of screenshots;
4. Where to get more information (links to help, an example of context-sensitive help, and a link to the full manual);
5. Three 'cheat sheets' of menu paths and keyboard shortcuts for the common tasks.

There is a skill to generating the 'Getting Started' document: it's got to be short, relevant, and memorable. 

For simple software, it is sometimes the only documentation that needs to be provided to the user. 

If it isn't that simple, there are always going to be things that you missed, and problems that new users and owners run into at the very start, which you hadn't anticipated: you have to keep on top of this, keep talking to new users, and keep updating the 'Getting Started' guide. 

Many vendor's don't. 

There's also the problem of shipping software into a vast universe of (say) mobile devices, all of which are slightly different, and many of them will be out-of-date: in this case, there will be a need for separate 'Getting Started' help documentation. This, too, needs to be short, relevant, and memorable:  a searchable 'Q&A' or FAQ page is probably best.

For much of the world's software, Stack Overflow is all of the searchable 'Q&A' in existence for someone getting started. Now there's no disgrace in The Stack being the best source of answers for some products - we're pretty damn' good! - but I have a very low opinion of vendors who are so bad that the 'Stack is the *only* source.

Stack Overflow is the first place that users will go when your documentation lists a short set of twee little 'troubleshooting' problems and doesn't provide a link labeled *'What to do next, if none of it works for you'*.

If that's what the 'help' section of your 'Getting Started' guide looks like, please consider a new career contributing methane to a landfill site.

Onward, then, to The Big Document in 'The Documentation'...

#### The User Manual:

A user manual has three audiences:

- Beginners;
- Occasional Users;
- Experts or 'Power Users'.

There is a fourth item, for a 'non-audience' of very special users:

- Idiots.

I say 'non-audience' because they probably won't read the manual at all, but they are still represented in the *'do not do this'* information that protects you against legal liability.

In the first three cases, your User Manuals have to support two separate and distinct activities:

1. Learning to use the application and exploring additional functions after mastering the basics (the 'Training Manual' function);
2. Looking up answers to specific questions about the functions of the software (the 'Reference Manual' function).

These two functions aren't really compatible: if you can fit them into a single document at all, you're going to structure it in distinct sections.

Structuring your information is really the key to all of this: far fewer people would ever look for 'Read the manual!' information on Stack Overflow if the manual provided a structured way to both read and retrieve the things they need to know.

I can't offer any guidance on the overall structure of your document - that's got to reflect the way it's deployed and used - but I can give you a tactical hint:

If every point that the users need to know is structured into these three sections, you will succeed in writing Good **Documentation** for beginners and for expert users:

1. A memorable, meaningful, discoverable heading;
2. The easy explanation and easy instructions;
3. The details and the difficult stuff, if anyone needs to know more than the easy stuff.

You'll notice that I've mentioned beginners and experienced or expert users there, but not the 'Occasionals'.

Note that occasional users aren't beginners: they are often experts at one particular thing! So how does documentation work for them?

They don't need to wade through the introductory material, over and over again; but they do need 'reminders' if tasks they are performing (say) four times a year for quarterly reporting have a lot of separate steps.

The point about reminders isn't just that they are brief and to the point: they have to be easy to find, or you're forcing the occasional users to plow through *all* the documentation anyway.

A hint: a user manual with 'cheat sheet' sections of bullet-point lists of actions are very, very good for this: someone will adopt one of these and print it out for their own team's 'occasional user' task if you've done this documentation well.

So we get back to the structure of your document: does it make sense to each type of user, and does it work as both a training and a reference manual?

That's The Big One: now for the complicated one...

#### The Support Manual:

I'm going to deal with this lightly because there are very few generalisations that can be applied to good support documentation.

But the basics are:

1. An overview of how the software actually works;
2. The location of the error-reporting and debugging tools;
3. ...And a worked example of their use;
4. An 'FAQ' of the most common user error reports with worked examples of their resolution;
5. A suggested 'first line support' script...
6. ...And a searchable wiki or Jira-like vendor page of support issues, with details that are good enough to constitute a 'worked example' of each reported issue was resolved or worked around.

Some vendors do this; and some don't.

Some vendors supply 'recipe' instructions on what to do, but are very reticent about explanations: they don't quite believe that user support is often provided by people with more technical knowledge than the users.

In fairness, some vendors provide user support from a low-cost helpdesk with significantly *less* technical knowledge than the users, or even the office furniture; and it is perfectly logical for them to provide support documentation in the form of animated GIFs with catchy music and a popup reminding their supervisor to administer a 'Good Boy!' doggy-chocolate reward at key points in the 'support' process.

But the better class of vendor does provide a detailed support manual aimed at a technical audience, and so should you: it's hard to do, because we're a demanding audience... But doing it well is a reflection of your courtesy to your fellow-professionals, and some of us are going to remember having to work with the support manual at your last employer, when you are being interviewed for your next job.

I am, of course, assuming that you did it superbly.

But, in all cases, Stack Overflow is **still** the 'go-to' destination for answers, even when better information is available from the 'RTFM' official source.

Here's why:

### The essential concept of discoverability:

I don't need to point out that both the teaching and reference functions of a manual should be searchable - although the training will lean towards a 'start from the beginning' narrative for some products - but the reference section and the 'Support Issues' list should be **discoverable**.

This means that it's not just possible to 'look up' details of the things that you know by name or keyword:  *'looking up the details'*  means you know what they are, you know exactly what they are called, and you have a pretty good idea as to where the information is already.

If you know all that already, great, but...

**Discoverability is about finding out what it's called and where it is**

...Yes, even if you're from a different technical background to the authors of the document.

**Example:** *"Oh, I can see that I need the word 'dimension' to do this, not 'table'..."*

**Counter-example:**  *"Stooopid newbies are expected to know that we call this 'a dimension' and they need to spend an afternoon reading the training manual if they don't"*

So the short answer to your second question is:

#### Stack Overflow has discoverability.

You can discover answers here that you won't find on other sites, even in the 'official' documentation, because unlinked information left as  *'look it up if you know exactly what it is and where'*  isn't 'documentation'; it's a digital sarcophagus.

And if you can't discover it by Googling into the vendor sites, the 'Stack provides the ultimate discovery tool: asking people who actually know.

Answer (score -12):

Stackoverflow:

## HAS REPLACED DOCUMENTATION.

That's how the world works.  The world gets better.  Read some Toffler books.

You might as well say: "Oh, I'm sick of these hotel review sites: people should get back to buying proper Fodor's travel guidebooks."

Or you might as well say: "How do I get people to stop using amazon.com and go to normal brick and mortar shops?"

Or, "How do we stomp out this Ebay use and get people back to Christies?"

Or, "How can we eliminate OkCupid use and get people back to using Bars and Discos?"

Or, "However do we stop people using this git + open source business, we must get back to jobs in companies."

It just doesn't make any sense.  FORGET documentation, it's just stupid.

It was never a good idea. Documentation had it's little chance for a couple years and it's over.  It's just something young people in the future will make jokes about from the Big Government era.

{Consider, have you ever bought - say - any Apple product.  Did you see a manual in the box?  No. Consumer goods are leading the way - documentation is just stupid; it's gone; it's historic. Nobody liked it and now it's history.}

SO + internet text search is here.

---

As I explain it below:

....When I can't remember "**what the hell is the syntax of addRange in List**..." I never, ever, ever **go to the msdn doco page.** Instead, **I just start typing in Google** the characters "List T add Ra..." and **by the time I've typed those characters**, I have the total answer.

(AND INDEED, as a highly non-trivial additional matter - this is a world-changing concept - I also instantly have, a **vast range of additional ephemera, critical information** about the issue, including - just one example - any new topical changes, any gotchas, and (astoundingly) all thinking on the matter by the handful of engineers/etc very closest to any topical issues on the precise technological item in question. Et cetera.)

Why would you possibly go "RTFM"? **Google search is built in to everything everywhere** in both text and speech, including eg my refrigerator door. And indeed the SO info-sphere is a critical part of the "google-info-everywhere" nexus.

Comment: People *aren't* searching. The same search that would turn up an SO answer would turn up the documentation. Also, without documentation, where is the information from SO answers supposed to come from? Trial and error? Reading the source? (Reading the binary, for closed-source systems?) The people I'm worried about here have an instinct to ask for help before looking for the information themselves, whether that information comes from documentation, duplicates, or other sources.

Comment: Rubbish. When Microsoft creates a new API, do they just let people figure it out themselves and post on stackoverflow? No, that would be ridiculous. They publish *documentation* on MSDN. Programming is a little more complicated than using an ipod. Documentation is required.

Comment: user2 -- if that's true, there's just a bad technology problem on SO.  As a user types a new question, the site should just find all the answers. the site should further understand the user "is a newbie" and more aggressively present the info.  So, they need a few lines of PHP to fix the problem you identify. The problem you identify would be not unlike saying "people don't know how to search, using the google page" .. if you see what I mean.

Comment: @Blorg - I appreciate your gutsy "rubbish", but you sound like someone in the Kindle era moaning about how paper books and bookshops are still culturally important, or something. Nobody has ever, does ever, or will ever read Microsoft's documentation. You just google (which largely means "SO") for the answer, to even the simplest question.  Just as software has gone "open source", all information is now open source. Nobody wants to and nobody does read the stupid doco, because there's a zillion infosphere tuorials, articles, thoughts in half-english, and SO entries on the subject.

Comment: So, as you ask rhetorically, **"When Microsoft creates a new API, do they just let people figure it out themselves and post on stackoverflow?"**. That is **precisely, literally, exactly, to the letter** what is happening with, say Swift.  Which is a whole new language, a whole new milieu, not merely a new API. Nobody ever has, does, or will look at **the stupid Apple pages on Swift**. Everyone just instantly .. googles on SO.  Look at the staggering amount of info on Swift on SO/the infosphere (after a few days). Nobody gives a toss what "the Man" (Apple in this case) has to say on the matter.

Comment: The infosphere, created by you, my other SO friends, and my "sisterhood generally" of iOS engineers planetwide, is wildly better than the crap, government-esque doco "by the Man" which Apple provides.  **They should just stop pretending to provide it.**  You can (today, now) become a top Swift engineer, i.e. you can write software that will hold up suspension bridges, by absolutely not looking at the silly Apple doco, but by reading the zillions of thoughts in the infosphere.  Trust SO :)

Comment: Where do you think the people who post answers on SO get their information? The aether?

Comment: You are talking about *tutorial(s)* **not** *documentation*. You are confusing those two terms.

Comment: @Blorg - you're just making **"rhetorically funny" comments**. The "rhetorically funny" answer would be "they watch the apple videos where engineers talk about it." (Actually that's not just funny, it's true: people so hate "manuals" that all the really deep source stuff on iOS (ie, on SO, on the infosphere) comes from those talks.) The fact is "everyone" **(say, 999 people out of 1000) will never, ever, ever touch "The Man's" documentation about Swift.** They'll get every detail from SO searches.

Comment: @abh - no, you're quite wrong.  When i can't remember "what the hell is the syntax of addRange in List<T>..."  I never, ever, ever go to the msdn doco page.  I just start typing in Google "List T add Ra..." and by the time I've typed those characters, **I have the total answer, AND, importantly, a vast range of critical information about the issue, including - just one example - any new topical changes, any gotchas, etc**.  Why would you possibly go to the manual?  Google search is built in to everything everywhere.

Comment: (Recall too that if you have any, say, android device, lying around on your desk: you need only open your mouth and start saying the words "List add range syntax..." and before you can finish talking you'll have a vast array of information .. and as I outline in the previous comment, spectacularly better info than the doco, which is all-but useless, it's "basic".)

Comment: I'm proud that **two free thinkers** have voted-up this post, which is so obvious. It's not even the case that "in two years everyone will think like this", it's already happened.

Comment: I write docs, and I can assure you that plenty of people read docs. Not only do I know that from analytics, but we get a steady cadence of feedback and bug reports that make it clear that people read the docs quite carefully.

I think the premise of this thread ("People don't read the docs") is too simple. Different people read different docs at different times; some people prefer docs, others videos, others a Q&A approach to their questions. (People often prefer different types of information at different times in their learning curves.)

Comment: Joe, are you serious that you think people who answer questions on SO got their information from watching videos? Also, I like how people who agree with you are **free thinkers** (I guess the downvoters are **sheeple**).

Comment: @blorg, yes I'm completely 100% serious. "open messy infosphere" pseudo documentation has and will replace traditional "official manuals".  {regarding videos, if you're an ios engineer, the video presentations by apple engineers are the only place you can get real arcane knowledge on tricky issues; the doco is useless. that's what i was referring to.} I don't in the slightest think anyone is a "sheeple," and i've never insulted anyone in my life. i assert that anyone who can seethat "open messy infosphere" pseudo documentation has/will replace traditional "official manuals", is a free thinker.

Comment: @mike referring **to the OP question at hand**.  ther's an old saw on QA sites like this:  "you idiot questioner, just go RTFM!"  that old saw: **IS STUPID**.  For even the simplest, most basic question .. you know those questions like "what's the second parameter of this call??" .. where "traditionally" (like 15+ years ago) we'd all say "holy hell, go RTFM".  Today, that response **is plain wrong**.  because of, quite simply, google search engine technology, we now have an entirely new cosmos. To simply copy and paste what i said above........

Comment: ....When i can't remember "**what the hell is the syntax of addRange in List<T>**..." I never, ever, ever **go to the msdn doco page.** Instead, **I just start typing in Google** "List T add Ra..." and **by the time I've typed those characters**, I have the total answer, AND, importantly, a **vast range of additional ephemera, critical information** about the issue, including - just one example - any new topical changes, any gotchas, etc. Why would you possibly go to the manual? **Google search is built in to everything everywhere** in both text and speech, including eg my refrigerator door.

Comment: "And it was amazing the feeling of power that gave him."

Comment: Alls I'm saying is that we have plenty of quantifiable evidence that people DO go to the docs.