# YAFQ - Yet another FAQ Question - Setting up a topic based FAQ?

Tags: discussion

So there have been a number of questions about adding a FAQ feature to SO.  For instance:

[Setting up a FAQ for the C++ tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252874/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag)

There are a lot of good arguments there, and I don't want to rehash them.  My question is more about what we SHOULD do if we want to organize a topic based FAQ.

Of course there is the Frequent tab in the Question search, but this is decidedly more needle-in-a-haystack than a true FAQ.  What separates a FAQ is that a FAQ is curated, while an arbitrary search for frequently linked items is much more noisy.

As I see it, there are several possibilities in the given system.

1. A single Topic-FAQ wiki-question.  This has the advantage of "all FAQ questions in one place"
2. a topic-faq tag, such as the C++-Faq.  I find this to be less useful because it doesn't allow commentary by the curator to be associated with the list of items.  Additionally, it's a lot more work to monitor for tag abuse than to watch a single question to prevent non-faq questions from being added.
3. Both 1 & 2 above?  Seems like double the work.

Would it be wrong to just go ahead and create #1 and let it evolve?  Or would this be considered off-topic (or at least inappropriate for SO itself, would a topic-based FAQ belong better on meta?)

Obviously, a FAQ can also be considered too opinion based, so that is also an issue.  Lots of people get worked up about what should and shouldn't be a FAQ.

It would be nice if SO had a feature that would allow questions/answers to be limited only to moderators and those with badges in the topics tagged by the question.  Even better would be tags that only moderators/topic-badged can add, thus a question could be tagged 'topic-faq-proposed' and a moderator/topic-badged person can change it to topic-faq and not have to worry about random people marking things as topic-faq.

**In the absence of any "curated" topic support in SO, what is the consensus about creating FAQ's and the most accepted way to do it?**

EDIT:

Seems like much of what i'm looking for can be accomplished with the tag-wiki, a function which I didn't even know was there.  The term "info" is a bit underwhelming for discoverability of FAQ's though.  But that's ok.

Comment: The tag-wikis already have the option of including the FAQ for the specific tag -- I have opened this question earlier today for guiding newbies to those, as they contain significant amount curated information, and it is just a question of finding a way to make better use of that -- add your comment here if you think this is the same question (overlap/duplicate) of your intent: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261867/should-we-guide-programming-newbies-to-the-tag-wikis-for-tutorials

Comment: Having a giant wiki-question regrouping all the QAs would be messy in my opinion, especially for large topics like C++. Instead couldn't the FAQ be a somehow special page auto-generated based on the number of duplicated questions (which really are literally frequently asked)? The criteria for inclusion in the FAQ could be refined based on the up-votes, number of views, etc. That will allow the page to be objective and always up-to-date.

Comment: @Soren - You're absolutely right.  I had no idea that the Tag Wiki was even there.  "info" is a bit too terse and misleading, I think.

Comment: @this.lau_ - That's what the frequent tab already does, but there's a huge quality difference between frequently linked questions and a curated FAQ.  Questions are linked for a lot of reasons, and in a single question, you might have half a dozen or more links to similar questions, rather than a more definitive wiki'd FAQ-link.  I like the tag-wiki that Soren just pointed me to, it actually does what i'm looking for.  I'm less concerned about discoverability (though that would be nice) as I am about simply having a place for FAQ's.

Answer (score -9):

I think it's worth remembering that, the whole concept of "FAQs" or indeed **any other supposed division of information**, is:

*completely and utterly useless, and 20 years out of date.*

The universe runs on google search: that's all there is to it. Say you need to know the address of the Pensione Rivazza hotel, or perhaps the syntax of the List add command.

Here's how the universe now works:

Since google search is absolutely everywhere (it's in voice, text, it's on my refrigerator, it's included as you type in every thing everywhere...)

Step 1: Start typing the characters "Pensione Rivaz..." or "List add..."

Step 2: There's no step two, you now have all the universe's information on that topic , presented in front of you -- useful documentation sources, critical commentary on same, important topical issues, known hot problems, fascinating historical aspects, and so on. All presented in an amazing concordance.

**The overwhelming point is, the original categorisation of the different info sources ... "this! is a faq!"  "it's my! blog!" "we write doco! at google!" and so on ... is of no interest whatsoever and means: nothing.**

I was discussing the same thing here:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261302/294884

So if you set up a "faq" ... nobody cares.

When I start typing "c++ whatever sytnax...", google will give me all the info.  Whether it appears on your personal blog, some doco site somewhere, or a page labelled "faq" ... or whatever.

By the way, notice in the above example, I deliberately mispelled / confused the name of the hotel in question.

But you'll instantly find out everything about it, regardless.  Every review (professional! faq! pro-sumption! whatever...), the weather there, the cultural conditions, the upcoming date of the famous event in the city in question, video snips from well-known action franchises set there, etc etc etc etc etc.

**From about 2005 onwards, it is completely quixotic - more plainly, "utterly pointless" - to worry about categorisations like faqs.**

It's like the old-fashioned panic on SO about comments! questions! answers! etc.  Nobody cares.  When you start typing a topic, the internet (call it "google search" - whatever) gives you the sum of known knowledge on it.

Comment: That's great, for you the expert that can differentiate bad results from good results.  For "newbies", they spend hours, if not days slogging through bad results to find something that resembles what they need (since they don't know what they need, they can only do whatever the results tell them).  Fact is, search only works when you know exactly what it is you need.

Comment: Unfortunately that's wrong, Erik.  It's unfortunate because **I really wish there was absolute knowledge**, but there just isn't.  A web page that has the letters "faq" at the top is no more or less likely to be worthwhile, or useless, than any other information source.  *the expert that can differentiate bad results from good results*  There is no magic trick to differentiating good information from bad. The same applies to every google search ever made.  It makes no difference at all if you are an expert or amateur or novice in a field.

Comment: Who said anything about "absolute knowledge"?  What a strawman argument.  You're being ridiculous.

Comment: (1) "for you the expert that can differentiate bad results from good results".  It's no easier or harder for an expert in a field or a newbie, to "differentiate information".  (2) "newbies spend hours / days slogging through bad results.." this is simply wrong.  (3) If some of those results happen to be labelled "Faq" or "wikipedia" or "Official Documentation": it changes nothing. (4) "search only works when you know what you need" this is completely wrong. the entire raison d'etre of search is that it will tell newbies what they are looking for, if you give it a topic.

Comment: This does not appear to be an argument against setting up a FAQ, it is just an argument in favor of allowing the FAQ to be indexed by Google.

Comment: [There are tons of tutorials online, and 99.98% of them are junk that teach bad habits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261867/can-we-automatically-guide-programming-newbies-to-the-tag-wikis-for-tutorials?lq=1#comment49964_261891)