# How to handle mistagging with *-faq tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I found there are 4 tags with *-faq:

- [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B-faq) (239 followers, 147 questions)

  > Provides a collaborative, community-edited C++ FAQ
  >   4 asked this year
- [r-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq) (61 followers, 125 questions)

  > is created to group a limited number of questions discussing problems that come up regularly on the R tag. It is not the official FAQ
  >   4 asked this year
- [rust-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-faq) (1 follower, 6 questions)

  > Provides a collaborative, community-edited Rust FAQ
- [racket-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/racket-faq?sort=newest) (0 followers, 1 question)

Is there any guidance from the community to what to include to such tags? I could only find a [proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261870/2886003) about how to make a faq tag.

The question that made me ask I wouldn't make it to the r-faq tag[.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39908415/2886003)

Comment: gain another 66 rep and clean them up yourself?

Comment: Yes :D, but that wouldn't prevent other users to add or create new ggplot2-faq or python-faq.

Comment: join our misery in  the land of janitorial work and scolding (or not)