# What should we do about the [c++-faq] tag and its questionable uses?

Tags: discussion, tags

**Disclaimer:** this issue was somewhat raised before in [How to handle mistagging with *-faq tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337353/5740428), but got very little interaction and didn't explore the subject deeply. I don't have enough expertise in other languages, so I will focus on [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq).

### The tagging situation

The [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) is explained through the excerpt:

> Provides a collaborative, community-edited C++ FAQ.

This description is fairly clear, but the way it is applied to questions is not. Let's look at some examples.

#### Popular examples

- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
  This question is a community wiki, and is obviously community-edited. It also mentions that it's an FAQ question in its footnote, clearly identifying itself as [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq). The use of the tag seems appropriate here.
- [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/5740428)
  This question contains a footnote and clearly describes itself as [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq). However, none of the answers on this question are community wikis. The author has been able to farm thousands of reputation points off of this Q&A. Is it still in the spirit of [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) to not make the Q&A "community-edited" in the purest sense?
- [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/5740428)
  This question is tagged [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) and it contains a community wiki answer. It doesn't contain a footnote, but based on the wiki answer, it seems reasonable to apply the tag.
- [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/5740428)
  This question is tagged [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq), but there aren't any signs of it being "collaborative" or "community-edited". Neither the question nor the answers are community wikis, and the question contains no footnote. The top comments still describe it as an FAQ answer, but given the lack of identifying details, the use of the tag is questionable.
- [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/5740428)
  Other than the tag, there is no obvious reason why this would be a "community-edited" FAQ. There is not footnote, no community wiki answer, nothing. User @sbi [has retroactively tagged this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/589575/4), and this probably conflicts with the intent of the author since they never advertised the question as "collaborative" or "community-edited".
- [What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9387610/5740428)
  This question advertises itself as a C++ FAQ, but is now closed for being off-topic for the website.

#### Recent examples

- [What is an mdspan, and what is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75778573/5740428)
  This question is wiki-style, as the author has provided both question and answer. However, it is not a community wiki and so it is unclear to what extent it is intended to be "community-edited".
- [Global variables - When to use static, inline, extern, const, and constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76999585/5740428)
  This is my own Q&A. The question hints at it being community FAQ, and the (only) answer is a community wiki. This seems like appropriate use.
- [What is std::expected in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68368581/5740428)
  Here, the author did not tag it [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) originally, this was only done by the author of the (non-wiki) answer after the fact. This edit likely conflicts with the intent of the author and it's questionable whether this question can be considered "frequently asked" given that it only has 20K views and is asking about a very recent feature.
- [Difference between preprocessor macros and std::source_location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63683286/5740428)
  The author retroactively tagged this question [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq), 20 days after posting it. It is unclear in what way this Q&A is "community-edited", and it definitely didn't get enough exposure to qualify for "frequently asked".

### Summary of the problem

Out of the 169 total [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) questions, numerous questions perhaps shouldn't be tagged for:

- not being community wikis and thus serving a secondary purpose of farming reputation while not being "community-edited" in the strictest sense
- being improperly tagged in a way that seems to conflict with the intent of the author
- having been closed for being off-topic
- being dubiously tagged [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) with no clear signs of why this tagging was applied

Even if you think that all these questions can and should be tagged [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq), we need clear criteria for when [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) should be applied. If tagging is opinionated without clear guidelines, you get edit wars.

**What should be done about this situation? Should there be a community effort to remove this tag if inappropriate? What would the criteria for such a tag removal be? Should the tag be burninated? Should everything be left as is, but with clearer guidance on when to apply the tag?**

#### Further notes

**Note on the original Meta post:** See also [Setting up a FAQ for the C++ tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252874/5740428), which the question which started the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) project, but contains no clear consensus on when the tag should be applied.

**Note on the tag wiki:** The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b-faq/info) states that the tag is used for "frequently asked questions", however, this is obviously too low of a hurdle and could be applied to thousands upon thousands of questions. Stack Overflow also lets you sort questions by numbers of visitors or by score, which arguably serves this purpose already. It is also too low of a hurdle considering the excerpt.

Comment: Personally I don't see a reason why an FAQ should absolutely be community wiki. FAQ means "frequently asked question" not "questions that are community wiki". Furthermore community wiki doesn't add that much to collaborative editing since we have suggested edits if one does not have full edit privileges.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm not saying that it's an absolutely requirement either, and I don't think so. However, making it a community wiki clearly matches the excerpt's requirement of being "community-edited". If [c++-faq] is merely used to identify frequently asked questions, then I don't think the tag has a right to exist. What is "frequently asked" depends on the domain, and is opinionated. Is it appropriate to set up a [c++-faq] question for a C++26 feature that's *probably* going to have questions frequently asked about it? Who knows. Tagging should not be opinionated. Otherwise: edit wars.

Comment: Do you have any recent examples? All of the currently listed ones are at least 10 years old.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yeah, I have added some recent examples to this post now. To be fair, tagging is a means of finding questions, so in my opinion, even if a question is 15 years old, a discussion about its tagging still has merit.

Comment: I don't know why that tag (and others with similar name) was created but I guess it was used by the community to curate / maintain a list of duplicate targets commonly used by them. I guess the problem here is that the tags can be added by anyone without consensus. Maybe there can be a feature request to create this list automatically according to number of times a question is used as a duplicate target or maybe this is where collectives could potentially be used where the collective would have a process to select FAQs.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat A collective would be nice, but to my understanding, Stack Overflow collectives need some authoritative leadership, like Amazon itself for AWS. I'm not sure if it's in SO's interest to create language collectives that are run by the committee or something. I agree that part of the issue is that anyone can apply this tag without consensus. I don't think that it needs to be automatically managed though. Frequently duplicated questions are typically high in score and visitor count, so we already have all the tools necessary, an the tag isn't really necessary.

Comment: Community wikis already provide the indication this tag was meant to indicate.

Comment: "and so it is unclear to what extent it is intended to be "community-edited"." <- All questions are to be community-edited. Marking as community-wiki is mostly an indication of how much it is legitimate to "go to town" with the edit.

Answer (score 9):

**[c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) should be burninated.** This would solve all questions about when it should be applied.

Firstly, note that the most highly upvoted answer on the post that started the FAQ ([Setting up a FAQ for the C++ tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252874/5740428)) argues against the concept of the C++ FAQ. With a vote of `+63/-8`, there is overwhelming consensus that the FAQ project is problematic.

Besides this answer, there are additional tagging issues that have become clear to me recently. In short, community wikis do a better job at encouraging edits from the community than [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq), and whether something is frequently asked is opinion-based. This tag does not bring enough value to the community to keep existing.

##### 1. [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) is a meta-tag which possibly encourages collaboration

The current excerpt states:

> Provides a collaborative, community-edited C++ FAQ

I have seen at least two interpretations of this so far:

1. "Collaborative" and "community-edited" are redundant, as this applies to all posts on SO anyway. The tag description merely says that questions tagged this way are "questions that are frequently asked". The excerpt should be updated and this redundant information should be removed.
   *This perspective is popular, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426733*
2. Alternatively, the tag has a strong connotation of inviting edits from the community because it emphasizes "community-edited". This makes the tag very difficult to apply to questions because inviting collaboration is something only the author can do themselves. If the author doesn't want to advertise a Q&A as "Please edit this, community!", then adding this tag to their question would conflict with their intent.

Whichever interpretation you see as correct, it's questionable that a tag states "collaborative" and "community-edited". If someone encourages their Q&A to be edited by the community, they can communicate this clearly by making their post a community wiki.

##### 2. Whether something is frequently asked is subjective

If we remove the "collaborative" and "community-edited", and make the excerpt something like:

> Frequently asked C++ questions.

... then another problem becomes clear. Namely, applying this tag is an opinionated decision.
Questions like the following arise:

1. **Is something frequently asked only if it's asked on Stack Overflow?** After all, it could be that a question is frequently asked elsewhere, but there is no evidence on SO itself that it is a frequent question. What external sources should we consider, if any?
2. **Does popularity imply frequency?** For example, [What is the '-->' operator in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/) has over 10K upvotes, but it's debateable whether people frequently ask about `-->`. It's not a pattern that is commonly recommended, or found in real code; it's more of a neat trick that people find interesting. Some people may use the sheer popularity of this question as rationale for tagging it [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) though.
3. **Can an author add [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) to a new question?** After all, the author might speculate that a question will be frequently asked in the future. They might do so because the question is about a brand new version of programming language, and they suspect it will become frequently asked over time.
4. **Should the tag be removed if the question used to be frequently asked, but not longer is?** There are plenty of historical questions about C++03 or lower, etc. One day, C++11 is going to be rarely used, and a lot of Q&As about it are going to be superseded. If a domain shrinks over time, does that justify removing the tag?
5. **Does a question have to be frequently duplicated to be frequently asked?** Duplicates might be a good indicator for "frequently asked". However, such a metric ignores all the questions that are never asked because someone quickly found the canonical. What about deleted duplicates? Not everyone has access to deleted questions, to my knowledge.

Overall, none of these questions have an obvious yes/no answer, and it would require a huge community effort to find consensus for all of them. Whether a tag should be applied to a question should not be opinion-based, and a tag for "frequently asked questions" encourages opinion-based tagging.

Perhaps we could have an [faq] meta-tag applied automatically by Stack Overflow, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: *"there is overwhelming consensus that the FAQ project is problematic."* - yeah it's faqed. **badum pssh**. I'll give one reason... it makes no sense on Stack Overflow. The whole purpose of this site is to capture frequently asked questions and give them readily available answers. What's the purpose of creating explicit lists within implicit lists exactly, beside having something for people to lord over?

Comment: It might be time to dismantle this tag indeed. It is a so-called meta tag and has been allowed because it is supposedly well-maintained, although I can't find any evidence of that any longer. I don't think there's a criteria that each post there must be a community wiki, but it has to at least be a FAQ and the posts must have somewhat decent quality too.

Comment: Something like "What is an mdspan" cannot possibly be a FAQ, this is a very niche question. In fact lots of these so-called FAQ are about new, more or less exotic features. Just because some veteran users find them interesting doesn't make them a FAQ. A FAQ is something that is actually frequently asked, such as "What is the result of `i++ + ++i`".

Comment: Personally I think the tag wiki works much better for FAQ, for example the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info), though I'm quite partial since I was the one pushing to implement that. But when doing so back in 2017, we looked at existing models such as [tag:c++-faq] and found it problematic - the community consensus and arguments against using a tag was summarized [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349563/584518).

Comment: The fact, that burninating a tag resolves questions about when to apply it, is not a valid reason to burninate it. There may be other reasons, but that's not one of them. If the tag is otherwise valid, and the question of when to apply it is tricky, then there's a tricky question which needs to be addressed, not just swept aside.

Comment: @Lundin: I'm the author of "what is an mdspan". While I agree that the number of people asking that question is not very large as of yet - it is of the "what is an X, and when should I use one?" category of question, where X is a C++ language, or standard library, construct. We have those for smart pointers, for spans, for explicit, for launder, pointer to class data member, etc. That said - I am not against converting some/many of these into tag wikis. Although I have to admit it will be rather painful for my reputation.

Comment: @einpoklum In case of C++ the question is often rather "should I use it at all?" and in many cases the answer should be no. Because there's such an enormous amount of features and all of them comes with an enormous++ amount of poorly-defined behavior. The ambition of a FAQ shouldn't be to cover the whole language, particularly not in case of C++. It's a FAQ, not a book. As for tag wiki, I mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) - scroll down to the FAQ section. Not to be confused with _community wiki_ which is posts that anyone can modify.

Comment: @Lundin: "Should I use it at all" is not so much a FAQ question, since its form is usually "I am trying to do thing Y; should I use construct X?" - and this is the stereotypical (valid) SO question. With c++-faq-ish questions available, you refer the user to, or quote from, the c++-faq-ish answer, then apply it to the case of Y, and tell the asker whehther they should use X or not. I am aware of the distinction between tag wikis and community-wiki posts.

Comment: @einpoklum The culture of the C++FAQ tag rather seems to be "here's feature Y now lets try to find a X problem that it solves". Notably, even though feature Y solves problem X that someone is asking about, it is not necessarily a good solution for that problem, or for _any_ problem. A significant part of the C++ standard comes with redundant or blatantly dangerous features that probably shouldn't be used for any purpose. This is true for any language, but C++ stands out by the sheer volume of such features. We need not write a SO post to cover each and every one of these, that's not a FAQ.

Comment: @Lundin: I disagree with that observation, for two reasons. First, C++ features usually arise from concrete use cases and it's in fact IIANM a requirement for adding anyting to th standard. Second, at least in my personal experience, I've written these after noticing that I'm answering concrete questions and wanting to expand about something (e.g. a span) more than the context of the individual question necessasitates. So instead of repeating myself with overlaps, I'd rather collect those bits and pieces into a single answer with more grativs.

Comment: @einpoklum The only criteria for something to get added to the standard is majority vote. Anyone can join the ISO WG. Put enough goofballs in it and _anything_ will get added. This is a problem that all ISO committees had since the dawn of ISO.

Comment: For C++ specifically, it tends to go: "Here's A, it solves B." Gets voted in. Now we can solve problem B, but as a side effect we get problems C D E F G H I J instead. I could `throw` a Torvaldsish tantrum about at least ten such C++ features, but that's another story. They even have a whole separate WG for the sole purpose of trying to list all poorly-defined behavior in the standard, because doing so is such a vast and seemingly endless project...

Comment: @Lundin: That's really not how the C++ WG works - niether procedurally nor materially.

Comment: And yet: C++11, C++14, C++17, C++20, C++23. Revising the programming language with a major revision every 3rd year means that the WG is running amok. There are not nearly enough news in computer hardware nor computer science to motivate this never-ending flood of features, particularly since a lot of the changes are of dubious usefulness. And so there's no wonder that the "UB WG" never can keep up with the collateral damage caused by this flood of features. KINC principle - Keep It Needlessly Complicated.