# Are comments linking to humorous gifs especially unwanted?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, deleted-comments

I recently posted a comment on the following question: [Reversing colorbar without reversing a text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27494133/2777181), which I find a little amusing in itself. I used [a popular gif](http://img.pandawhale.com/post-37094-Tom-Cruise-WHAT-gif-Oblivion-I-wDog.gif) (inoffensive and safe for work) that expresses puzzlement in a way to tell OP that the reported behavior seemed very unusual to me. The comment was up-voted at least 4 times before it disappeared.

From what I understood of this thread: [Are inoffensive tongue-in-cheek comments considered bad form?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261076/2777181), light-hearted comments are generally discouraged, and I understand that. But there is *an ocean* of trivial/unhelpful comments, so I'm wondering what was special about mine so that mods bothered to delete it.

Comment: SO is not reddit. Don't use "reaction gifs" or advice animals or similar things, it's just noise - and made much worse by the fact it's _off-site_ noise; one has to follow the link to if the content is relevant at all.

Comment: [If you use gifs for humor, use them wisely](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276684/improvements-to-stack-overflow/276686#276686)

Comment: Sometimes, instead of seeing it as encouraged vs discouraged, I prefer to see it as "if you do post it, don't expect it to stick around for long".

Comment: This one probably missed.

Comment: SO users are entitled to be offended about *anything* you post that is not an answer.  It just takes one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was deleted because it didn't meet the criteria [Tim Post lays out in his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261083/16587):

> There is a place for tongue-in-cheek humor on Stack Overflow, but it takes quite a bit of finesse to pull it off. **The comment has to be something informative, something of value that could conceivably influence an edit to improve the post**, just delivered in a comical way. (emphasis mine)

I don't think [this GIF quite did it](http://img.pandawhale.com/post-37094-Tom-Cruise-WHAT-gif-Oblivion-I-wDog.gif).

I didn't notice it until another user flagged it. I found it via the moderator queue.

Answer (score 8):

Comments should be used for the following (non-exhaustive list of) reasons:

- Request clarification from the poster.
- Highlight possible issues with the post where you're not confident enough to make the edit yourself.
- Helpful links to the relevant documentation that probably don't answer the question but might be useful.

i.e. helpful stuff

What they shouldn't be used for is comments like:

- "thanks"
- "me too"
- "this should be the accepted answer"
- "great answer"
- "this answer is wrong"
- non-documentation links of any kind (reaction gifs being just one type)

There's enough noise on Stack Overflow without people adding to it.

If you see comments like these then please flag them as "too chatty" or "not constructive" - which is what happened here, someone flagged your comment. If they get enough flags they'll be automatically removed, or if a moderator's clearing the comment flags they'll more than likely get deleted.

The fact that people upvoted your comment should not be taken as meaning that the site as a whole approves of it.

Comment: This is useful information, but it doesn't really answer my question. Since there are hundreds of comment falling in any of your second list's categories that stay undeleted, what's especially unwanted in a humorous link? Some of the comments to my post seem to give good reasons.

Comment: @CapeCode ChrisF will have to say for certain, but it is likely that a mod did not single out your comment and instead was responding to a flag from another user.  Mods generally do not have the time or bandwidth to go seek out comments to delete.  If you think a comment is not constructive or is no longer relavant, but all means flag them.

Comment: Surely "this answer is wrong" *is* valid -- when followed with an explanation?

Comment: @Jongware - nope. What you should do is down-vote and provide the correct answer.

Comment: @ChrisF Leaving a "this answer is wrong because <reason>" can help the answerer to fix their answer. Of course it's helpful.

Comment: @user202729 that sort of comment is useful and I never said it wasn't.