# Should we clarify what forms of humorous commenting on Stack Overflow are allowed?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, community-moderation

After a brief comment exchange on a comment I left that, admittedly, was meant solely as an attempt at humour (and thus did not actively contribute to the solving of the question) I realised that I think we have a bit of a policy gap when it comes to humour on SO.

Strictly speaking, the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315198/are-humorous-comments-considered-acceptable-content) is "no", humour is not considered acceptable content of a comment.

But I think we should, as SO contributors and community members, think about the effect that has on our wider community and overall SO culture.

We have all (most likely) seen some great examples of humorous comments (I won't link to them now) that are funny (to us), don't seem to cause harm (they are not at the expense of someone else), and maybe even perk you up a little in your day.

[This dated](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) (but still relevant) blog post from one of SO's co-founders Jeff Atwood brilliantly exemplifies the problem but falls a bit short of arriving at a clear "humour policy".

In the spirit of being agile and iterative, what about clarifying what we mean by "only a certain amount of fun will be tolerated, and always with steely, businesslike frowns" (which is funny!) by actually giving an example, or some sort of framework to work with.

What if we added a section like this to the Help Center for humour so that results are not nil:

[image: Insert American vs Australian English Jokes Here]

**When is it okay to post a humorous comment, and what are some examples of humour etiquette?**

While StackOverflow is at its core a Q&A site for programmers and enthusiasts, if you feel you absolutely must share something witty:

- keep it friendly: don't make jokes at other peoples expense (i.e. by dissing or dismissing them)
- pair it with constructive input: making someone smile is great, but making someone smile after posting a great answer is even better
- keep it culturally agnostic: you might find religion X or philosophy Y funny, others might very well live by it
- never, ever post the answer "42" to a question on Stack Overflow, unless you absolutely know the Ultimate Question

Comment: Stack is a "no nonsense, low noise to signal ratio, focused on answers/questions" site.... allowing humor feels like it goes against that. And, humor is so culturally dependant, you risk offending people more often than you seem to think. All in all, it seems that we'd be opening a can of worms. Now, that being said... maybe a piece in the help center to make it clear you should **not** do this wouldn't be out of place imho. Likely not what you want, though

Comment: _"You're allotted a daily quota of 3 fun. If you exceed this quota, your quota will be penalized 1 fun for the following month. If another users finds your fun not to be fun, you will be fun-banned 'till the next full moon."_ The moment you start creating rules about what is and isn't allowed as "humour", it's no fun any more.

Comment: Instead of using your personal, opinion-based ideas of what fun consists of, check the manual. [man fun](https://linux.die.net/man/6/fun) gives "fun - draw pixels accumulating in clusters ". _This is the definition of fun_. As long as you stick to drawing pixels in clusters, SO won't have any problems with it. Though include a MCVE just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Use your jugement, you can make a joke, but make sure not to hurt anybody's feeling. That as became complicated in 2019

Comment: @Cerbrus Have one fun for that.

Comment: The downvotes are accumulating! Which is, admittedly, an interesting little jibe from our witty community members (and will destroy my reputation by a thousand tiny cuts).

Answer (score 11):

Humor is tricky

While it often feels good to show off one's clever wit, it's often at the expense of the person who is on the line -- the one asking the question, and this is doubly so on meta, when it is someone asking why they've been banned from answering questions (the post that generated your current question). I think that some light humor is OK, but always think twice before posting, and *always* try to see your post from the shoes of those who matter most: those who are asking the question and those who might feel pain from it.

A Google search strategy for similar questions:

- [humor site:meta.stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=humor+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com)
- [humor site:meta.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=humor+site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I completely agree, to be honest it was our comment exchange that partly inspired this, and you were right to say that my attempt in that instance was not particularly positive (it was at someone else's expense). So, upon reflection, I thought maybe it would be worth putting that in writing somewhere - this sort of exchange doesn't feel like nonsense to me, but rather one that is engaged with the question "what sort of things do we think are okay on SO" (hence the meta post)

Answer (score 7):

It's all about the tact.

Generally speaking, this is a serious site for serious commenting and for clarifications and improvement requests only (no, seriously). That said, often times people don't mind humor when it's in good fun and adds levity or wit to a situation.

That said ...

When your humor is at the expense of someone else, especially in a negative context, as was the case in the situation you described above, that becomes less okay. Due to the nature of things here, people often come to meta upset and angry at what happened to them on the main site. Sarcasm or Irony in these situations can be supremely disheartening to someone who made a good faith inquiry about a grievance they have, specifically if they continue to get negative feedback here.

If you're in doubt, just refrain.